# Error: pyMySQL is not working in spiders of scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pymysql

when I am importing pyMysql library in the scrapy project in python it is giving an error that no module found. I want to ask how can I import pyMysql library in python file of scrapy project. And when I am importing pyMySQL in simple python it is working properly.

in the spider , which was generated by command "genspider spider_name (url)" i used this code which is giving error .

```
enter code here

import scrapy
from amazon.items import AmazonItem
import pymysql


class AmazonProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "AmazonDeals"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]

# Use working product URL below
start_urls = [
    "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01IO0QWJA","https://www.amazon.in/Mi-Redmi-5-Gold-32GB/dp/B0756RF9KY"
]

def parse(self, response):
    items = AmazonItem()
    title = response.xpath('//h1[@id="title"]/span/text()').extract()
    sale_price = response.xpath('//span[contains(@id,"ourprice") or contains(@id,"saleprice")]/text()').extract()
    category = response.xpath('//a[@class="a-link-normal a-color-tertiary"]/text()').extract()
    availability = response.xpath('//div[@id="availability"]//text()').extract()
    items['product_name'] = ''.join(title).strip()
    items['product_sale_price'] = ''.join(sale_price).strip()
    items['product_category'] = ','.join(map(lambda x: x.strip(), category)).strip()
    items['product_availability'] = ''.join(availability).strip()
    yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) module is installed:

```
python -c "import pymysql"
```

This command should returns nothing if everything is ok.

If it returns a *ModuleNotFoundError*, so [install the module](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html) by using pip:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

Comment: it is already installed and is working in simple python program

Comment: Could you provide some sourcecode to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: The problem might come from your environment. I only get your error if I try to execute your script directly from my shell. If I execute the script using python [scriptfilename], everything is ok.

Comment: but when i execute using python [scrptfilename] it is giving me error that scrapy module not found

Comment: do you use conda ?

Comment: try using it, create a new environment, activate it, install scrapy in it and for sure, it will work

Comment: it is running in anaconda prompt but not in simple cmd why?

Comment: Check your path environment variable.Check the difference between your conda environment scrapy installation and your default python shell. Maybe your default python interpreter check the modules in your old lib library